# How to know the server in reachable or not in android?

Tags: android, server, wifi

Hi, I want to know is my website in reachable or available?

whit this method I know my device is online or not:

```
protected boolean isOnline() {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You are connecting to Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You are not connecting to Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and with this method I want to know is URL available or not:

```
public boolean isServerReachable(String serverURL) {

        ConnectivityManager connMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = connMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL urlServer = new URL(serverURL);
                HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlServer.openConnection();
                urlConn.setConnectTimeout(3000); //<- 3Seconds Timeout
                urlConn.connect();
                if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Server is Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Server is not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

then I create a Button, when clicked this two method will call, like this:

```
if (isOnline()) {
    isServerReachable("https://www.google.com/");
 }
```

when I click the Button if WiFi is Off this Message will show:

> You are not connecting to Internet!

and when WiFi is On this error will show:

```
> Process: com.rastari.salar.salytest, PID: 3864
>     android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>             at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
>             at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
>             at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>             at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>             at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
>             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
>             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
>             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
>             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
>             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
>             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
>             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
>             at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
>             at com.rastari.salar.salytest.MainActivity.isServerReachable(MainActivity.java:78)
>             at com.rastari.salar.salytest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
>             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 06-25
> 06:14:16.845    1557-1557/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 1557:
> eglCreateSyncKHR(1207): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE) 06-25
> 06:14:17.614    1708-1891/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ CMD_START_SCAN :
> connected mode and no configuration
```

How can I determine that the server is available or not?

Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to `isServerReachable()` method because you are doing the networking operations in the UI thread, which will result `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Instead to running them directly execute the method in a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or another worker `Thread`.

```
 public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return isServerReachable(URl);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            //Perform operations.
        }
    }
```

Comment: I create this method to execute Task:

`private void isServerReachableMethod() {
        IsServerReachableTask task = new IsServerReachableTask();
        task.execute();
    }`

when I call it this error will show:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Comment: @SalarRastari The error is because of Toast messages, remove the Toast messages, then it will work.

Comment: will you please tell me how to use AsynkTas to get String URL and send back Boolean from checking a server status (available=true or not=false)?
such a method like this: public Boolean getServerStatus(String url){ }

Comment: If you use the above AsyncTask you can get the status in the onPostExecute(). but you can write as a method which will return the status, because it will return in the background thread.

Comment: I write a method like this: `private void getServerStatus(String serverURL) {
        IsServerReachableTask task = new IsServerReachableTask();
        task.execute(serverURL);
    }`
how can i get Boolean from getServerStatus method?

Comment: You cannot return the result in getServerStatus because you will get the result in onPostExecute()

Comment: OK, so I have to define a Boolean variable like `Boolean serverStatus = false;`  in the main then in `isServerReachable` method under `if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == 200) {` write `serverStatus = true;` or in `onPostExecute()` write `serverStatus = true;`?

Answer (score 1):

Call your method `isServerReachable()` from an [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Since your doing a network call on main thread of your application, it crashes.